# 'File already exists in database: caffe.proto' on make runtest

Tags: caffe

When I tried to install the latest caffe on my MacbookPro (El Capitan), I got following errors. What's wrong? How to fix it?

I found a few similar issues on this site, unfortunately shown fix  seems ubuntu specific.

Thank you in advance.

```
bash-3.2$ make runtest
make runtest
.build_release/tools/caffe
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:57] File already exists in database: caffe.proto
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1164] CHECK failed:   generated_database_->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: generated_database_-    >Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
make: *** [runtest] Abort trap: 6
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error. In my case, switching from Protobuf 2.6.1 to the latest Protobuf Version (i.e. 3.4.1) resolved the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is typically an issue with libprotobuf. You need to re-install protobuf debian and then rebuild caffe as shown below:

1. Uninstall the existing protobuf:
   sudo apt-get remove libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
   sudo apt-get remove libprotobuf-lite8 libprotoc8
   sudo apt-get remove python-protobuf
2. Re-install protobuf. Follow all the steps given at [steps to install protobuf (2.6.1) debian](https://gist.github.com/samklr/0b8a0620f82005e7f556).
3. Rebuild caffe